# Why `ru_maxrss` returns more usage than expected

Tags: linux, memory

I'm testing a program runner. When I'm using GNU time 1.9 to test the code below

```c
// nul.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main()
{
  struct rusage r_usage;
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r_usage);
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof r_usage);
  printf("%ld\n", r_usage.ru_maxrss);
  return 0;
}
```

compiling with

```
gcc nul.c -o nul
```

and run with

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./nul
```

, it reports

```
144
576
    Command being timed: "./nul"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1424
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 61
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 4
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

The Maximum resident set size doesn't meet the output of the program. With more testing, the `maxrss` size which GNU time reports is always ~1400kB. And testing the code below

```c
// nul2.c
int main(){ return 0; }
```

compiling with

```
gcc nul2.c -o nul2
```

and run with

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./nul2
```

GNU time reports ~1000kB `maxrss` usage. However, I didn't use any memory space in my program. So why the `maxrss` usage is not ~0kB, and how to measure the actual memory used in the program?

---

UPD:

I wrote a null assembly program.

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int  $0x80
```

compiled with

```
as -o nul.o nul.s
ld -s -o nul nul.o
```

and tested with GNU time.

```
    Command being timed: "./nul"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 61%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 128
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 13
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 0
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

There's also 128kB max RSS usage. How does it come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are similar to mine here.

Do not forget that your program uses libraries. (For example, function `printf` is part of your program. And its buffers are allocated when the program starts or later, or both. Recall that also the code counts towards RSS if it is loaded into the memory.) This explains both the non-zero number and the fact that the number increases before the process finishes.

If you stop the execution of your process somehow (by a read instruction or debugger), you can inspect its memory using `/proc/<pid>/...` or, for example, by the slow `lsof` program.

In particular, your program is using `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (or similar)
which is 2.2MB on harddisk (not all of that is necessary loaded).

---

It is likely that

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./nul2 "$(seq -w 1 16000)"
```

reports a bit higher number because also the command-line becomes part of the process' memory.

---

---

UPD:

Now you moved to much lower levels. Congratulations. You stepped over the possibility of using the C compiler with options that make it not  include the standard libraries. (A random [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817070) in a possibly wrong direction.)

I think you already know some answers `Why` (which is how you formulated the question) (So this question is already answered, may be good may be worse) and possibly you want to file a new question like "How do I compile a program using less than xxx of this/or/that kind of memory". I think you should explain your motivation. Do you want to run a process with a minimum footprint? Why? Are you about to use a minimal hardware? Or are you about to run a million of processes?

For your assembler program, we may run it in `gdb` (with `break _start` and `r`) and look at

```
cat  /proc/222226/maps     # the number is PID of the process
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 103:04 1049144                           /home/h/tmpdir/asm.tmp.1
00401000-00402000 r-xp 00001000 103:04 1049144                           /home/h/tmpdir/asm.tmp.1
7ffff7ff9000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

and

```
cat  /proc/222226/maps | tr a-z A-Z | awk 'BEGIN {print "ibase=16";}; {print $1}; ' | bc -l
-4096
-4096
-16384
-8192
-135168
-4096
```

but I do not know how much that contributes to RSS or whatever.
Looking at `/proc/222226/smaps` I do not see much of rss there.

BTW: I already mentioned, that the content of the command line contributes to used memory. The same holds also for the environment.

**What does `/usr/bin/time` actually report?** How does it start the program? If it starts it by `fork` (explicit or hidden in a library combo), its own memory usage will contribute to the used memory.
The following looks funny:

```
$  /usr/bin/time -v nonexisting
/usr/bin/time: cannot run nonexisting: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
    Command being timed: "nonexisting"
...
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 768
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 40
```

So `time` uses almost a mega of a fresh memory to recover from
a failed `exec` (or something) and to print
a message `cannot run...` and makes 40 page faults on the action.
(May be most of the mega is spent in unexpected clean-up and hard work towards exiting of the forked process, but anyway.)

Summary: I suggest to start a new question, rather `How` then `Why`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm working on an online judge to grade programs by accounting running time and memory usage. I think that the Turing machine architecture is suited for memory accounting, i.e. accounting "the length of tape" that the program used. But there will be some redundant parts in the accounting. If the redundant parts are known, I can just account and subtract them from the accounting, to get an accurate value. Maybe a fine-grained memory accounting will help, but it will be hard to implement (modify the kernel maybe).

Comment: To the question of why we need an accurate value, the accurate value is there. :)